# ASP.NET - How to hide gridview EmptyDataTemplate in PageLoad()

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hide, emptydatatemplate

In ASP Web Forms solution I want to hide **EmptyDataTemplate**  in Page_Load method? how to do this ?

**This is front end:**

```
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div id="hideInPageLoad" class="row" runat="server">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="mt16 white p16 text-center">
                            <%# LoadResource("SHGHSearchInFund_NoResultsFound") %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

**This is back end:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearch.Text))
            {
                hideInPageLoad.Visible = false;
            }
```

but error is this..... :

> Error 1   The name 'hideInPageLoad' does not exist in the current context

Comment: probably you able to hide whole grid if you havent data to display.

Comment: so, you can add ID to your grid/list/whatever which contains this emptydatatemplate and hide it in page_load.

Comment: My id on my gridView is gvAcheologyMonuments, with property i use ?

Comment: Assume that gvAcheologyMonuments.Visible = false;

Comment: Where i have a data?

Comment: I want where i havent data hide EmptyDataTemplate

Comment: not sure that I understand your problem correctly, but you can try this

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearch.Text))
 {
  yourgridview.Visible = false;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `hideInPageLoad` is inside Gridview EmptyDataTemplate, Could try out this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         if(!IsPostBack){
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearch.Text))
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl Emptydiv=(HtmlGenericControl)gvAcheologyMonuments.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("hideInPageLoad") ;
                    Emptydiv.Style.Add("Display", "none");
                }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the Error?

Comment: this is the Error ---> https://s32.postimg.org/galyvchsl/L_29_EF_tmp.png

Comment: I paste behind code outside my if (!Page.IsPostBack) in Page_Load method ? Where im wrong ?

Comment: Why has twice Controls[0] ?

Comment: I am not able get it. Could you please put the debug point and run the code to know on which line it gives Object Reference not set to an instance? why Outside ` if (!Page.IsPostBack)` ? I think it Should be inside.

Comment: Controls[0] is the Child Table within the GridView and the next Controls[0] is the GridView EmptyDataTemplate Row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118810/discussion-between-gohyu-and-rojalin-sahoo).

Comment: gvAcheologyMonuments.Controls[0].Controls[0].Visible = false;